# Does global inbox have a separate url and page?

Tags: support, global-inbox, network-profile

Is it possible to view my stackexchange global inbox on a separate page, not just in the "supercollider multidropdown" or whatever the notifier is TM called.

Comment: When I go to my network profile - in your case [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/302564/naxa) - there is a tab called inbox. Is it something like what you're looking for? (Of course, I only see it on my profile page, not on yours or that of other users.)

Comment: @Martin I suspect that's the answer naxa is looking for, yes. You should post it as such!

Comment: Your URL, naxa, would be http://stackexchange.com/users/302564/naxa?tab=inbox I think.

Comment: What @AndrewBarber said.

Comment: @Oded: Well, what about notifications though?

Comment: @Martin, AnderBarber, Oded, indeed what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha yes good question, that would be interesting to! and best to find out in one go

Comment: @Madara no central place for notifications just yet, surprised nobody suggested to add such tab to the network profile. Feel free to be the first to ask! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183963/does-global-inbox-have-a-separate-url-and-page?noredirect=1#comment561793_183963) I am posting my comment as an answer.

When I go to my network profile - in your case [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/302564/naxa) - there is a tab called inbox. (Of course, I only see it on my profile page, not on yours or that of other users.)

Your link  should be https://stackexchange.com/users/302564/naxa?tab=inbox - I guess `https://stackexchange.com/users/USERID/?tab=inbox` should work in general.

EDIT: Here is a link which should work for any user: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox

Comment: There's also a plain json version of the inbox at _sitename.com/inbox/genuwine_ example - http://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine

Comment: I've been looking for this forever — you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

The raw `HTML` inbox is currently (11-Oct-2015) at **[`stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox`](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox)**; and the Achievements list is at **[`stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements`](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements)**.

Comment: great! now for something completely different. could we use httpS links please? back on topic I like this raw page from your answer

Comment: @naxa Edited to make the links HTTPS. They aren't redirected to a non-HTTPS version, so they should be secure.